# Javascript onchange select boxes

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I have a drop down box that posts to the page on a submit button.

I am trying to remove the submit button and make it so it posts when you change the drop down as its a much better way to work!

The value = "submit_button" and it gets picked up by:

```
// Check if form has been submited
if ($_POST['submit_button'])
{

// If form has been submited set $newCookieValue variable, set cookie and refresh webpage
$newCookieValue=$_POST['dbselector'];
```

The code I am trying to use is:

```
<form>
    <select name="dbselector" onchange="this.form.submit()" style="margin-left:0.5em;">
    <option value="option_1" selected="selected">option_1</option>
    <option value="option_2">option_2</option>
    </select>
<noscript><input type="submit" value="submit_button"/></noscript>
</form>
```

When I change the drop down from option 1 to option 2 it reloads the page but I don't think its posting the values as I can check the values by adding this into the top of the page:

```
<br> <?php var_dump($_POST['dbselector']) ?> 
<br> <?php var_dump($_POST['submit_button'])?>
```

and they both return NULL?????

Comment: Accidentally choosing the wrong option when using controls like this is the height of frustration and often, the reason I'll not use a site any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to state in your form that you are using `POST` via `method` in order to tell the form which HTTP method to use:

```
<form method="post">
   ...
</form>
```

Comment: Missed that out when I re wrote the form! have been up a long time today thanks for your assistance.